# Is there Pattern to manage : Taxonomy + search (Lucene) + Permission

Tags: lucene, taxonomy, spring-security

I want to develop my own website administration.
Here is my problem, I want to use these technologies :
* search : LUCENE/SOLR
* users' permission : ACEGI (SPRING SECURITY)
* taxonomy (I do not not if there is technologies for this)

So I do not have experience in these technologies. I would like to know if somebody understand my situation in order to help me...I think there is a logical coherence between theses elements but I do not why...Do I need to develop these functionalities as if they were totally independant ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've had some success in building web sites using [Grails](http://www.grails.org/). Grails is the Java-world equivalent to the Rails framework, and is built on top of Spring, Hibernate, and Groovy. It also interfaces smoothly with existing Java code, because it runs in the same virtual machine and is, basically, Java. In addition, Grails has a rich collection of plugins, including ones for [search](http://www.grails.org/plugin/searchable) and [authentication/security](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core). I am not sure what taxonomy you're referring to, but that may be something you can model using Grails Domain classes.

Comment: I would like to construct my little 'CMS'... What I call taxonomy is the fact that : if I create a new topic so it will create a new page in my website, and if I create one new sub-topic so it will create another new page related to it parent. Does a pattern exist for this ?

Comment: @nzaero If I understand you correctly, you're talking about views on objects. Grails makes that pretty easy to do. The topic-subtopic relationship is also a simple thing to model in grails, assuming it is a has-many relationship.

Comment: Ok, you understand well my case. But what happen, is that first, I will use SPRING ROO. Then, I am looking for a modular architecture (maybe using **nodes** such as Drupal) that will let me have a flexible interaction between the content, it structure (taxonomy) and the full-text search engine. This is quite complex, and you can give me a very good reason to use GRAILS...but I would prefer to invest myself on SPRING ROO (for other reasons...). tkx